# Incorrect Looping - CS50 Mario

Tags: c, loops, do-while, cs50

So I'm solidly new to programming and currently trying to do my CS50 Pset. The task is to have the code print out the correct number of hashtags in a pyramid formation. My code does that but I have an error in my loops where my code simply stops after satisfying the condition and I would like it to print the hashtags and run the loop again. I really cannot figure out what my error is and would greatly appreciate help!

```
int main(void)
{ int n = -1;

do  
{
    n = get_int("Height: ");  
}

while (n < 0 || n > 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (i + j > (n-1))
                printf("#");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
                printf("\n");

            } 

}
```

My target output is

Height: 2

1 hashtag
2 hashtags

I'm getting that output but my code just stops after that and I can't figure out how to fix that. I tried using a do while loop around my code and that did not work either.

Comment: "my code simply stops after satisfying the condition". Loops end when the condition becomes false. If you want it to continue, you need to do something like wrap that code in another loop. If that's not what you mean, show the target output, and show what you're getting.

Comment: # != hashtag...

Answer (score 0):

You put a semicolon (';') after the condition of your `while` loop. That means that the loop body is this empty expression.

Please adopt a consistent coding style, indent your code correctly, and always use curly braces on each control structure.